# setting up Scene Builder with NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: scenebuilder, netbeans-8

I am using:
Mac OS X 10.10.1

NetBeans 8.0.2

SceneBuilder 8.0.0 downloaded from gluonhq.com

I dragged SceneBuilder to Applications folder.
When I go to Options>Java>JavaFX and set Scene Builder path to the Applications folder, I get the error:

> Selected location does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene Builder installation

Kindly guide me.

Comment: I'm not sure about Mac, but for Windows I had to install a NetBeans [nightly build](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) that included a patch to allow a different path for Scene Builder other than the Oracle's one.

Comment: @Rounak have you found an answer to how to install scene builder on mac yet?

Comment: @TonyStark No! I have not found a way.

Answer (score 30):

### Add Scene Builder to Netbeans 8.2

Here are the steps that I went through to setup Scene Builder:

- You can download *Scene Builder 8.2* [here](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/)
- **Install** the package (or run the installer) and find the install location

  - `/opt/SceneBuilder` on Ubuntu
  - `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Scene Builder` on Windows 10
- Then to link it to *Netbeans IDE 8.2* go to **Tools>Options>Java>JavaFX**
- Select **Browse** from the  *Scene Builder Home* drop down menu
- Finally navigate to the install location for **Scene Builder 8.2** and click *Open* and then *Ok*

To enjoy your newly found Scene Builder bliss, right click on a **.fxml** file in the Project Pane, and select **Open**.

---

**[Note:** One would use the *Edit* option to edit the .fxml code **]**

**[Update:** You can still download Oracle's *JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0* [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html), but Gluon is [now](https://dzone.com/articles/bye-bye-javafx-scene-builder) maintaining Scene Builder **]**

Answer (score 1):

1. Create project File > New project > JavaFX > JavaFX FXML Application
2. Download Scene Builder [follow this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html)
3. To link Scene Builder(no matter v1.1 or v2.0) do next steps:
   Service > Parameters > Java > JavaFX > Scene Builder start page > Preview
   and show path to unpacked folder. Confirm.
4. In your project right click .fxml and click Open.

Answer (score 1):

you can also download a javafx program an you specify well the path where you wan to install your scene builder;  on netbeans ... i have the version 8.0.2 then go to tools-> options->javaFX specify exactly the directory where you installed it (scnene builder) i tried on windows. Your project w'll automatically build then go to your file fxml right click and open

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your Java(JDK) version and Scene Builder version must be same. Scene Builder v10 is not compatible with Java v1.8.**

Comment: Highlighting important words are good but providing single statement and highlight whole sentence does not look good ever

Answer (score 0):

When you use NetBeans 8 in Mac OS X, if your NetBeans IDE is running, after installing SceneBuilder, you **can not** integrate SceneBuilder with NetBeans IDE **before restart NetBeans!** So the only thing you can do is restarting NetBeans, and NetBeans will find and integrate SceneBuilder.app in Applications folder automatically.